# What is the replacement for deprecated BasicAuthorizationInterceptor?

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, spring-framework-beans

I am using a new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor to do the basic authentication in oauth2.0. I can't find a replacement for the deprecated BasicAuthorizationInterceptor. Please help me with it

Comment: Use the [BasicAuthenticationInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/support/BasicAuthenticationInterceptor.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `BasicAuthenticationInterceptor` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

From the [BasicAuthorizationInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/support/BasicAuthorizationInterceptor.html) documentation:

> **Deprecated** as of 5.1.1, in favor of BasicAuthenticationInterceptor which reuses HttpHeaders.setBasicAuth(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), sharing its default charset ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8 as used here

Answer (score 0):

This is how solved my problem:

- in favor of `BasicAuthenticationInterceptor` which reuses `HttpHeaders.setBasicAuth(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)`, sharing its default charset ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8 as used here [1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/support/BasicAuthorizationInterceptor.html)

Comment: Hi, your answer doesn't show examples and may require further details. Please check on how to write awesome answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Using `BasicAuthenticationInterceptor` and also looking for the interface of  `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`

Answer (score 0):

I am answering a bit late but most of the above answers say BasicAuthenticationInterceptor can be used instead of  BasicAuthorizationInterceptor which is deprecated now. But if you see the implementation of both, you can find that in BasicAuthenticationInterceptor overriden intercept method as below:

```java
  public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
        if (!headers.containsKey("Authorization")) { // adds only if no Authorization header is absent
            headers.setBasicAuth(this.encodedCredentials);
        }

        return execution.execute(request, body);
    }
```

where as BasicAuthorizationInterceptor has below in the overriden intercept method:

```java
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        String token = Base64Utils.encodeToString((this.username + ":" + this.password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        request.getHeaders().add("Authorization", "Basic " + token); // no condition check
        return execution.execute(request, body);
    }
```

so as a  quick summary, BasicAuthenticationInterceptor checks if an there is a Authorzation headers and  adds only if not present but BasicAuthorizationInterceptor does not have that check.

So the basic solution is to create a Custom Interceptor which you might create referencing the BasicAuthorizationInterceptor class if you wanted to add multiple Authorization headers.

More info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/support/BasicAuthorizationInterceptor.html)